# switch on wifi client with hotspot already running on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, linux, hotspot

I'm writing an IOT application for a device with Rpi zero W as backend module. During the initialization process- Rpi switches on as Hotspot (on a particular channel) and gets the wifi home network credentials from the user. Now it needs to verify the credentials entered by the user for which the Rpi wifi client needs to start on the same channel as hotspot for both to work simultaneously.

I'm not able to ask pi to forcefully use a channel when turning on client mode and the workaround requires me to adjust hotspot channel to same as client and restart interface after wifi client starts.

This causes a momentary disconnection for the user connected to Hotspot of pi. Any ideas how both can be switched on simultaneously?

Comment: Are you aware that you can use the Pi as a client and AP **at the same time**?